# Ubuntu autopilot documentation

Tags: juju, maas, documentation, openstack-autopilot

Is there any documentation regarding autopilot and juju/maas implementation ?
Maybe a detailed architecture reference guide or so ?
I want to understand how the servers interact with each other and what purpose does each server serves. 
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here you can find the installation instructions :

[Canonical OpenStack Autopilot](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/install-openstack-with-autopilot)

Here you can find more details and information :

[Canonical Landscape Help](https://help.landscape.canonical.com/)

This documentation includes the Juju and MAAS implementation as well. You can try Canonical OpenStack Autopilot for free - but you will have to purchase Ubuntu Advantage when you use more than ten machines. Landscape Dedicated Server is the standalone version of Landscape that you can install on your own network. See general information on [Ubuntu Cloud](http://www.ubuntu.com/cloud) website.

Comment: This also has some information: https://insights.ubuntu.com/2015/04/10/maas-network-layouts-for-the-landscape-autopilot/

Comment: Thanks all. Andreas, I guess that link has more or less what I was looking for.